# How to validate NullPayload as null within a Groovy script in Mule 3.7.3

Tags: groovy, mule, mule-studio

Within a Groovy script I have the code:

```
if(payload != null && payload['result'] != null) {
    params ['result'] = payload['result']
}
```

The Payload received before coming to the Groovy component is **org.mule.transport.NullPayload**, so when I validate "payload" being `null` in the "if", it doesn't detect that is a `null`, which is expected since that class is intended for that purpose in **Mule 3.7.3**, so then what is the best practice to validate an instance org.mule.transport.NullPayload as a `null` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
if(payload instanceof NullPayload)
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks @tim, I used your way at the end, but my concern is more related to **"MuleLand logic"**, if they invented the `NullPayload` in the first time, shouldn't the same principles that apply in MEL do the same in any other Transformer? Is a little bit annoying treat a `Payload` as a `null` in MEL and as an Instance of a Class (`NullPayload` in this case) in another connectors, Transformers, etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
message.getPayload() == null
```

Did the job for me on Mule 3.4. Guess it´s still valid in 3.7.

There is a bug ticket registered in the MuleSoft Jira related to this: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6427

Comment: That doesn't apply because you are talking about MEL (Mule Expression Language) which it works just fine, the problem is inside the Groovy Transformer.